# Notepad++ match and delete values

Tags: xml, notepad++

I searched multiple posting and haven't been able figure it out.

I'm trying to delete all text from the value.

Sorry I forgot to mention their are other strings so I can't use Column Mode.

**I have:**

```
<string name="u" value="e45f"/>
<string name="u" value="bh90"/>
<string name="u" value="48hv"/>
<string name="u" value="Sh8D"/>
```

**I want:**

```
<string name="u" value=""/>
<string name="u" value=""/>
<string name="u" value=""/>
<string name="u" value=""/>
```

I would greatly appreciate it, if you could also explain how you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That are usual regular expressions

Find what `<string\s+name="u"\s+value=".+"/>`

Replace with `<string name="u" value=""/>`

Check regular exppression

Replace all

What is a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought it was much harder after trying for 3hours without any results.

Comment: it is very easy. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex search:
Find `value="[^"]*"`
Replace With `value=""`
This will retain your other content if there is any.